# Django - new style middleware process_response

Tags: python, django, middleware

I'm using the new style middleware in Django, and for some reason, it never gets to the 'process_response' part. If I understand correctly, it should occur after the

```
response = self.get_response(request)
```

in `__call__` function. But it never gets to the code beyond that line. What could be the reason?

This is how my middleware is defined:

```
class GlobalThreadVarMiddleware(object):
_threadmap = {}

def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    # Code to be executed for each request before
    # the view (and later middleware) are called.
    self._threadmap[_thread.get_ident()] = {}
    self._threadmap[_thread.get_ident()]['data_manager'] = DataManager()

    response = self.get_response(request)

    # Code to be executed for each request/response after
    # the view is called.
    current_data_manager = self.get_current_data_manager()
    current_data_manager.trigger_events()
    del self._threadmap[_thread.get_ident()]['data_manager']

    return response

@classmethod
def get_current_data_manager(cls):
    return cls._threadmap[_thread.get_ident()]['data_manager']
```

I'm using Django 1.10. This is the `MIDDLEWARE` parameter in settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [

'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'workflows.api.middleware.ApiCsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

'workflows.api.middleware.ExceptionMiddleware',
'workflows.api.global_thread_variables_middleware.GlobalThreadVarMiddleware'
]
```

It's the last one in the list.

This is the ExceptionMiddleware code:

```
class ExceptionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
def process_exception(self, request, exception):
    guid, code, error, data, error_status = ExceptionMiddleware.log_exception(request, exception)

    return JsonResponse(
        {
            "error_id": guid,
            "code": code,
            "message": error,
            "data": data
        },
        status=error_status
    )

@staticmethod
def log_exception(request, exception):
    guid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    error = code = data = error_status = None

    if isinstance(exception, FlowException):
        error = str(exception.message)
        code = exception.code
        data = str(exception.data)
        error_status = exception.code
    elif isinstance(exception, Exception):
        error = str(exception.args)
        code = 10001
        data = {'exception_type': str(type(exception))}
        error_status = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

    logging.getLogger(__name__).exception('error_id: ' + guid,
                                          {'request': request, 'error_data': data, 'error_code': code,
                                           'error_message': error})
    kwargs = {} #"exc": exception, "tb": exception.__traceback__, "value": error}
    if newrelic.agent.current_transaction() is None:
        app = newrelic.agent.application()
        if app.active is False:
            app.activate()
            newrelic.agent.register_application()
        kwargs["application"] = app
    newrelic.agent.record_exception(**kwargs)

    return guid, code, error, data, error_status
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using? Also, mind posting your settings.py (or at least the middleware parameter)?

Comment: Post the source of `workflows.api.middleware.ExceptionMiddleware` as well. How do you know that your middleware is even being reached? Do any earlier middlewares ever not call `get_response`?

Comment: I know it's been reached since I debugged it. It's the first time I'm using pure new style, so there wasn't `get_response` before

Comment: What do you mean by "it never gets to the 'process_response' part"? Your code doesn't use `process_response` anywhere.

Comment: I mean the part where it handles the response, which as I understand is right after the `response = self.get_response(request)`

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, because of my bad reputation.

I've seen your question before you edited it and it included `ImportError` that was directly related to your problem. Did you fix that `ImportError`?

New middleware style in Django works as advertised. I have implemented this new style many times and just to be sure, I even tested your code with certain modification to get it working and there is nothing wrong with it in general.

Comment: yes, I fix the import error. I have no idea why it won't pass that line. If it works for you, I suspect it's related to my other middleware(s).